# Xcode: Stencil/Cut text out of an Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, mask

I have a custom UIImageView class which has the following method:

```
- (void) cutOutText:(NSString*)stringToStencil;
```

I want the method to mask the image in a way in which the text is cut out of the image. The result of the method is to have an opaque image with a the transparent text in the centre. So far I have the following:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
[textStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
NSAttributedString *initialsString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: stringToStencil,attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:_initialsFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:_initialsTextColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle}];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.image.size, NO, 0.0f);
[self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
CGFloat fontHeight = _initialsFont.lineHeight;
CGFloat yOffset = (self.frame.size.height - fontHeight) / 2.0;
[initialsString drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, yOffset, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.image = result;
```

However this just prints the text onto the image. How do I create a mask and remove the text from the image instead?

Thanks

D